# Using titleps to add a pagewdth image as footer

Tags: titleps

I'm using titleps to add a footer which is an image made to take the whole page width, but it doesn't: the image keeps being pushed to the right by approximatively as much as the margin.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[top=1cm,left=2cm, right=2cm, bottom=3.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titleps}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{\today}
\newpagestyle{charte}{%
    \setfoot{{\img{chartegraphique.png}}}{}{}%
}
\pagestyle{charte}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Did I overlooked a titleps option ? Thanks for your help.

Here is the said image:[image]
The orange thing is supposed to be as close to the bottom left corner of the page as possible.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolute positioning is easily done using `tikz`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[top=1cm,left=2cm, right=2cm, bottom=3.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx,tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titleps}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{\today}
\newpagestyle{charte}{%
  \setfoot{\tikz[remember picture,overlay] \node[anchor=south west] at (current page.south west) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{Z49dh.jpg}};}{}{}%
}
\pagestyle{charte}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

This gives:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can try this code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} % Article sur papier A4 en 11 pt
\usepackage{graphicx}                 % Pour afficher des fichiers images
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}           % Document en français
\usepackage{amssymb}                  % Quelques symboles mathématiques
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-plot,pstricks-add} % Dessins avec PsTricks
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%ùles packages necessaires%%%%%%%%%%%%
 \usepackage{etoolbox}%
\usepackage{blindtext}%
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}%
\usepackage[skins,breakable,xparse]{tcolorbox}%
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=olive]{hyperref}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text} 
\pgfpagesuselayout{resize to}[letterpaper]
\setlength{\textwidth}{16cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{24cm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0cm}
\setlength{\voffset}{-2.5cm}
\setlength{\headheight}{35pt}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%les marges%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\setlength{\hoffset}{-18pt}         
%\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0pt} % Marge gauche sur pages impaires
%\setlength{\evensidemargin}{9pt} % Marge gauche sur pages paires
%\setlength{\marginparwidth}{54pt} % Largeur de note dans la marge
%\setlength{\textwidth}{481pt} % Largeur de la zone de texte (17cm)
%\setlength{\voffset}{-18pt} % Bon pour DOS
%\setlength{\marginparsep}{7pt} % Séparation de la marge
%\setlength{\topmargin}{0pt} % Pas de marge en haut
%\setlength{\headheight}{35pt} % Haut de page
%\setlength{\headsep}{16pt} % Entre le haut de page et le texte
\setlength{\footskip}{70pt} % Bas de page + séparation
%\setlength{\textheight}{708pt} % Hauteur de la zone de texte (25cm)
%%%%%definition pour inclurer une image dans une ligne
\newcommand*{\img}[1]{%%this command recienved one argument
    \raisebox{-.3\baselineskip}{%
        \includegraphics[
        height=6\baselineskip,
        width=6\baselineskip,
        keepaspectratio,
        ]{#1}%
    }%
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%definition pour inclurer une image dans une ligne
\newcommand*{\imag}[1]{%%this command recienved one argument
    \raisebox{-.1\baselineskip}{%
        \includegraphics[
        height=4\baselineskip,
        width=58\baselineskip,
        keepaspectratio,
        ]{#1}%
    }%
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\votretitre}{Université cadi ayad\\département de physique} % <- Titre de votre document
\newcommand{\votrenom}{}        % <- Votre nom
\newcommand{\votrecentre}{\img{Z49dh}}
\newcommand{\votredate}{ Examen corrigé mécanique du solide \\ fait le \today}              % <- Date de 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy} % En-têtes et pieds de page
\lhead{\votretitre}% Nom de la section en haut à gauche
%\chead{\votrecentre}
\rhead{\votrenom{}  \votredate} % Votre nom + date en haut à droite
\usepackage{lipsum}               % A supprimer... génère textes aléatoires
%%%%the footer of pages%%%%
%\fancyfoot[zone]{contenu}%L:left, R:right, C:centre
%\fancyfoot[L]{tutorial}
\fancyfoot[C]{\imag{Z49dh}}
%\fancyfoot[R]{adress.tutorial@gmail.com}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}
%pour forcer l'affichage d'une ligne horizontale, il suffit d'utiliser la commande \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}, pour les en-têtes 
%et \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}, pour les pieds de page.
\begin{document}         % DEBUT du document
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

to get something as:
[image]

Comment: LaTeX doesn't recognize the \fancyfoot function, I think it's a fancyhdr function, while I'm using titleps. But if I try using  \setfoot{}{\img{my_image.png}}{} (or any other position in \setfoot), the image keeps being pushed to the right.

Comment: you can try this change, in my reply

Comment: This still isn't what I'm trying to do: I want the orange part to stick to the bottom left corner of the page.